# what is the use of core registry in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, registry

while trying to perform crud operation i came across

```
$this->coreRegistry->register(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_AUTHOR_ID, $authorId);
```

to perform edit action they got the id param and registered in core registry.
I'm new to this and looking for logic and concept behind this...
why do we need core registry in magento 2?

Comment: Can you get my answer?

Comment: i can understand your explanation, but still whats the need for such concept.

Comment: I describe in the answer that core registry is used to store global variable. we can also use session for that but registry is more secure than sessions.

Answer (score 6):

> Core registry is used to store global variable. You can store global variables via `register()` method and fetch value of variables via `registry()` method.

In Magento 1, it was possible to register a global variable with the static registry method.

```
Mage::register('some_var', 'some value');
var_dump(Mage::registry('some_var'));
```

Many extensions, include core Magento extensions, ended up using this from controller action methods to pass variables into the views.

While its future is uncertain (not marked explicitly supported via an @api, but not marked @deprecated) Magento 2 does have a similar registry object that should help easy the transition for extensions. The class is `Magento\Framework\Registry`, and you can inject it in any constructor.

```
public function __construct(
    ... 
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->registry     = $registry;
    ...
}
```

and then set variables with

```
$this->registry->register('test_var', 'this is a test!');
```

and fetch those variables back (even from a different object – `Magento\Framework\Registry` is a `shared/singleton` object)

```
echo $this->registry->registry('test_var');
```

Source: magento-quickies.alanstorm

Comment: I describe in the answer that core registry is used to store global variable. we can also use session for that but registry is more secure than sessions

Answer (score 0):

Registry pattern is basically a pattern that allows any object or data to be available in a public global scope for any resource to use.

In Magento, you can register an object or data with Mage::register function,

Mage::register('identifier', $object_or_data);
After it is registered, you can call it with Mage::registry by passing identifier name:

Mage::registry('identifier');
You can also unregister an object at any time with Mage::unregister

Mage::unregister('identifier');
This is especially helpful transferring data between Models and Blocks without having to instantiate an entire class and load data.