# What is Registry in Magento2 and Why use?

Tags: magento2, registry

What is Registry in Magento2? Why use this. I want to know more detail about Registry. When we can use Registry in Magento2.

Comment: Don't ask the unnecessary question here, just google it.

Comment: @MilindSingh, What is unnecessary in the question?

Comment: Because this is not Google. You need read dev docs and other magento dev guides for the knowledge.

I see 2 more same type of questions here asked by you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this question's answer as your question is already asked here

[what is the use of core registry in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183996/what-is-the-use-of-core-registry-in-magento-2)

Alan Storm has written a great article on registry object see below link

https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-registry-object/

Comment: Can you expain here

Answer (score 0):

Basically **registry** is used to store global variable  You can store global variables via `register()` method and fetch value of variables via `registry()` method.

**How to create a registry in magento 2**

Here is the quick code snippet to help you work with Magento 2 registry objects

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
*/
protected $_registry;

/**
 * ...
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 */
public function __construct(
...,
 ...,
 \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 ...
) {
  $this->_registry = $registry;
  ...
  ...
}

/**
 * Setting custom variable in registry to be used
 *
 */
public function setCustomVariable()
{
  $this->registry->register('custom_var', 'Added Value');
}

/**
 * Retrieving custom variable from registry
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomVariable()
{
  return $this->registry->registry('custom_var');
}

/**
 * Return catalog product object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
  return $this->_registry->registry('product');
}

/**
 * Return catalog current category object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
 */
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
  return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}
```

I hope it helps!